# Add AzureDevOps Search as Chrome/Chromium 'Other search engine'

Tags: google-chrome, azure-devops, chromium

I want to add [Azure DevOps Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/code-search?view=azure-devops) to Chrome (or other Chromium) browsers so I can do quick code searches from the browser.

I got it working to search all repositories, but I want to also be able to add a specific "Search engine" for a specific repository.

**What's the Query URL to search a specific repository in Azure DevOps?**

*WHAT I HAVE SO FAR*:

I've added a new "Other search engines":

```
Search engine: Azure DevOps (all)
Keyword: code
Url: https://dev.azure.com/skykick/SkyKick%201/_search?action=contents&text=%s&type=code
```

[image]

And that works:

1. In address bar, type `code` and press tab:
   [image]
2. Search for `test`
   [image]
3. Press enter - be taken to Azure DevOps code results
   [image]

#### What's the URL format to include a specific Repository in my search results?

So I have a Repository `SkyKick.Example` - I'd like to be able to create an additional "Other search engine" that will search just that repoistory.

I looked at the Network tab looking for what url the app uses, and I tried this configuration:

```
Search engine: Azure DevOps (SkyKick.Example)
Keyword: example
Url: https://dev.azure.com/skykick/SkyKick%201/_search?action=contents
        &text=%s
        &type=code
        &lp=code-Project
        &filters=ProjectFilters%7BSkyKick%201%7DRepositoryFilters%7BSkyKick.Example%7D
        &pageSize=25
        &__rt=fps
        &__ver=2
```

But this doesn't load a page, just a wall of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool idea! This works for me for scoping it to just a repository

```
https://dev.azure.com/COLLECTION-NAME/_search?action=contents
&text=%s
&type=code
&lp=code-Project
&filters=ProjectFilters%7Besmith.dev%7DRepositoryFilters%7Besmith.dev%7D
&pageSize=25
&result=?
```